# SQL Server - DATEDIFF Function taking too long

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I've done some extensive research and I've concluded that the DATEDIFF function is making my queries run very slow.

Below is the generated query by Entity Framework and it does look readable enough hopefully.

Here's the Linq that generates the T-SQL:

```
model.NewTotal1Week = ( from sdo in context.SubscriberDebitOrders
                        where
                        (
                           sdo.CampaignId == campaignId &&
                           ( sdo.Status == ( Int32 ) DebitOrderStatus.New_Faulty ) &&
                           ( SqlFunctions.DateDiff( "week", sdo.Collections.FirstOrDefault( c => c.TxnStatus == "U" ).ProcessDate, DateTime.Now ) <= 1 )
                        )
                        select sdo ).Count();
```

In the query below, I would like to get a COUNT of all Collections which fall within 1 week from the time they were Processed to today's date.

Is there anyone that can help me get rid of the DATEDIFF function? I've seen examples online but I couldn't adapt it to my scenario, forgive me I'm not very genius yet.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM  [dbo].[SubscriberDebitOrder] AS [Extent1]
        OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Extent2].[ProcessDate] AS [ProcessDate]
            FROM [dbo].[Collections] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[DebitOrderId]) AND (''U'' = [Extent2].[TxnStatus]) ) AS [Limit1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[CampaignId] = @p__linq__0) AND (3 = [Extent1].[Status]) AND ((DATEDIFF(week, [Limit1].[ProcessDate], SysDateTime())) <= 1)
    )  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=3
go
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your code that is generating this SQL.

Comment: @Hakunamatata, I've updated my OP with the Linq that generates the T-SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT GroupBy1.A1 AS C1
FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) AS[A1
      FROM dbo.SubscriberDebitOrder AS Extent1 OUTER APPLY
           (SELECT TOP (1) Extent2.ProcessDate 
            FROM [dbo].Collections Extent2
            WHERE (Extent1.Id = Extent2.DebitOrderId AND
                   'U' = Extent2.TxnStatus
           ) AS [Limit1]
      WHERE (Extent1.CampaignId = @p__linq__0) AND (3 = Extent1.Status) AND 
            (DATEDIFF(week, Limit1.ProcessDate, SysDateTime()) <= 1)
     )  GroupBy1;
```

As mentioned elsewhere, you should change the date logic and get rid of the outer query:

```
      SELECT COUNT(1) AS A1
      FROM dbo.SubscriberDebitOrder AS Extent1 OUTER APPLY
           (SELECT TOP (1) Extent2.ProcessDate 
            FROM [dbo].Collections Extent2
            WHERE (Extent1.Id = Extent2.DebitOrderId AND
                   'U' = Extent2.TxnStatus
           ) AS limit1
      WHERE (Extent1.CampaignId = @p__linq__0) AND (3 = Extent1.Status) AND 
            Limit1.ProcessDate <= DATEADD(-1, week, GETDATE())
```

Very important note:  This is not exactly equivalent to your query.  Your original query counted the number of week boundaries between two dates.  This depends on `datefirst`, but it woudld often be the number of Saturday or Sunday nights.

Based on your description, the above is more correct.

Next, you want indexes on `Collections(DebitOrderId, TxnStatus, ProcessDate)` and `SubscriberDebitOrder(CampaignId, Status)`.

Comment: my SQL Server does not allow me: DATEADD(-1, week, GETDATE()). I did however switch it to DATEADD(week, -1, GETDATE()) and I get no results when I am supposed to. Any suggestion please?

Comment: Gordon Linoff, thanks for leading me to add indexes on the columns you suggested. Results are now returned in under 5 seconds...

Answer (score 4):

Its not the just DATEDIFF, any function on the column would cause query to do a SCAN on the underlying table/index

```
DATEDIFF(week, [Limit1].[ProcessDate], SysDateTime())) <=1
```

Above logic is fetching last week data? You can also write above without putting function around ProcessDate Column.

```
[Limit1].[ProcessDate] > SysDateTime()-7
```

Comment: I like your solution! +1 from my side, but you'd have to cast SysDateTime to `DATETIME` or better use `GETDATE()`... With `DATETIME2` you cannot perform simple additions...

Comment: The logic for this `datediff()` is not exactly the same as the original logic.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out GETDATE()...
@Balmukund Lakhani, I tried you solution and replaced SysDateTime() with GETDATE() and query still takes over 1 minute. It's biting me up a little bit on what's happening. The campaign with id 27 as per OP has less Collection, only 1434. When I execute the same query for another Campaign with more than 40K Collections the query finishes in less than 30 seconds. Not too sure what could be happening here... Any suggestions?